# Upload file Jersey with the same name

Tags: java, jersey

I follow this tutorial to post file to my server:
https://gist.github.com/aitoroses/4f7a2b197b732a6a691d.

But when users post 2 files with the same name, it will override the old file. Is there any way I can generate unique file name before saving it in server? Thanks for your help

Comment: sure, provide us what you have already tried

Comment: that's obvious . what if same file is getting uploaded ? then you will have multiple copies of same file.

Answer (score 1):

why you don't want to generate a unique code for each one ? do something like that.
append the name with the currentTimeMillis, your code should be like this

```
    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader) {

        String filePath = SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER +System.currentTimeMillis()+ contentDispositionHeader.getFileName();

        // save the file to the server
        saveFile(fileInputStream, filePath);

        String output = "File saved to server location : " + filePath;

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }
```

Comment: Great idea. Thank you

Comment: you are welcome accept the answer to let other people know this answer helps you